# Why do I get redirected to show instead of destroy route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

When I try to logout, I get into the function from the `show` route, instead of the `destroy` one.

This is the logout button in the view:

```
@if (Auth::check())
  <li>
    {{ HTML::linkRoute('account.destroy', 'Logout', Auth::user()->id) }}
  </li>
@endif
```

the `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as'   => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@index'
]);

Route::post('account/login', [
    'as'   => 'login',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@postLogin'
]);

Route::get('account/myprofile', [
    'as'   => 'account.myprofile',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@getPersonalProfile'
]);

Route::get('/account/activate/{code}', [
    'as'   => 'account.activate',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@getActivate'

]);

Route::resource('account', 'AccountController',
    ['except' => ['index']]);
```

And the `show` and `destroy` functions:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id)->first();

    return View::make('account.visit_profile')->with('user', $user);
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();

    return Redirect::route('home');
}
```

If I put `show` in the exceptions of the `resource` routes, and make a route for the logout:

```
Route::get('/account/logout', [
    'as'   => 'account.destroy',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@destroy'

]);
```

Then I am still being redirected to the `show` function.

I can't understand why does it happen like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a resourceful controller, the urls generated for the `show` route and the `destroy` route are the same, the only difference is HTTP verb used to access them. The `show` method is accessed using a GET request, and the `destroy` method is accessed using a DELETE request. Those two methods would be equivalent to:

```
Route::get('account/{account}', ['as' => 'account.show', 'uses' => 'AccountController@show']);
Route::delete('account/{account}', ['as' => 'account.destroy', 'uses' => 'AccountController@destroy']);
```

An HTML anchor tag is only capable of performing GET requests, therefore you cannot access the `destroy` action via an HTML anchor tag. The link will point to the 'account/{account}' url, but it will use a GET request, thereby taking you to the `show` method.

The basic solution is that instead of an HTML link, you will need a form that submits a POST request that contains a hidden field '_method' with a value of 'DELETE'. There are a couple options here.

1. Write the form yourself.

   ```
   @if (Auth::check())
       <li>
           {{ Form::open(['route' => ['account.destroy', Auth::user()->id], 'method' => 'delete']) }}
               {{ Form::submit('Logout') }}
           {{ Form::close() }}
       </li>
   @endif
   ```

   You can use CSS to make the form/submit button look like a link, if you want.
2. Use a javascript library to do this for you. There are a couple versions of a little library called 'restfulizer.js' floating around out there. Another option would be the rails jquery-ujs library (works outside of rails). The main idea behind these libraries is that all you do is add a new data attribute to an HTML anchor tag and the library will take care of generating and submitting the form for you. For example, if you had either of these two libraries loaded, your code would look like:

   ```
   @if (Auth::check())
       <li>
           {{ HTML::linkRoute('account.destroy', 'Logout', Auth::user()->id, ['data-method' => 'DELETE']) }}
       </li>
   @endif
   ```

   And that's all you would need.  The javascript would take care of the rest.